# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [75, 1]

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Can somebody tell me what kind of error is this and how to solve this (as picture given)

[image]

and here is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ep5pipeline.py", line 57, in <module>
    print (accuracy_score(y_test,predictions, normalize = False))
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 172, in accuracy_score
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 72, in _check_targets
    check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 181, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [75, 1]
```

Comment: On stack overflow, we prefer you indent your code by 4 spaces (most editors have a macro of tab for this) then post your source code (it will format it with syntax highlighting on StackOverflow), rather than a screen shot of code.  The reason being, we like to pull it up in our own editor and see what improves the functionality (and we hate having to copy text letter by letter from a picture).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'll improve it :D

Answer (score 1):

In function predict(), `return predictions` should out of the "for" iteration.

Besides, like Neil said, better to post sources code.